# Scoping aggregations with query filters

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I'm using top hits aggregation in elasticsearch. However when I add a filter to the query, it returns 0 hits (expected behaviour) and the aggregations however don't match the filter and return non zero documents. I was under the impression that aggregations work in the same scope as that of the query? Does not seem to be working that way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a top level `filter` instead of a filtered query. A top level filter is interpreted as a [post filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html) and executed after the query has been executed, influencing hits but not facets.

If you simply transform your post filter into a [filtered query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html), the aggregations will be correctly calculated on the results of your filter only.

```
{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "filter": // your filter as before
      }
   },
   "aggs": // now they will be correctly calculated
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Does the Aggregation happen before/after the filters?